# Background transparent in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, background

I have this CSS setting the background in a div but in IE8 it is showing as transparent. I can't see what I am doing wrong, any ideas?

```
.drop .holder{
  float:right;
  padding:16px 11px 15px;
  box-shadow:0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow:0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-bottom:1px solid #a1a1a1;
  background: #fafafa;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2ZhZmFmYSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiNlOGU4ZTgiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fafafa 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fafafa), color-stop(100%,#e8e8e8));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #fafafa 0%,#e8e8e8 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #fafafa 0%,#e8e8e8 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #fafafa 0%,#e8e8e8 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top,  #fafafa 0%,#e8e8e8 100%);
}
```

Comment: OT: have in mind the order of the declarations. you are declaring box-shadow first without prefixes and later with them, and it should be the other way around. Also you should add the -o and -ms prefixes if you want those to work on opera and ie 9/10. IE doesn't support inline svg

Answer (score 1):

Such things only work in modern browsers, not IE. You need to use non-standard things like this for IE:
`progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#909090')`

Also note your data url won't work in IE either and your SVG won't work in some versions of IE. They will work fine in the modern browsers though.